# swagger ui blank page with spring mvc

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm trying to integrate swagger 2 in my spring-mvc webapp (no spring boot).

It works when I go to /myApp/v2/api-odcs, I see the version, description and all my restControllers.

But when I try to access /myApp/swagger-ui.html All what I get is a blank page without even the green nav bar.

When I monitor the network I see that it get all resources (swagger-ui.html, css and js) succesfully (status 200) and it show the title in the tab : "MyApp: Swagger UI".

here's my configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
          .select()
          .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.withClassAnnotation(Api.class))
          .paths(PathSelectors.any())
          .build()
          .pathMapping("/")
          .apiInfo(apiInfo())
          .useDefaultResponseMessages(false);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        final ApiInfoBuilder builder = new ApiInfoBuilder();

        builder
            .title("MyApp - API")
            .description("desc")
            .version("1.0");

        return builder.build();
    }
}
```

and here are my dependencies :

```
compile group: 'org.webjars', name: 'swagger-ui', version: '3.5.0'  
compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: '2.7.0'
compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: '2.7.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my configuration, if that helps. I also specified the host and the path provider.

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@Profile({"!production"})
public class SwaggerConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private ServletContext servletContext;


    @Bean
    public Docket api() {

        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .host("localhost")
                .directModelSubstitute(LocalDate.class, Date.class)
                .pathProvider(new RelativePathProvider(servletContext) {
                    @Override
                    public String getApplicationBasePath() {
                        return "/myApp";
                    }
                })
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Note: If this is a SpringMVC application you may also need to remove `@EnableWebMvc`

https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/776